# Combinatorics and Linear Extensions

Tags: combinatorics

I’m considering the partially ordered set (X, ⊆) of subsets of the set X={a,b,c} of three elements. How many linear extensions are there?

I know that the subsets are:
∅, {a},{b},{c},{a,b},{b,c},{a,c},{a,b,c}

I’ve made a Hasse diagram which looks like a cube and I know that every linear extension must start with the empty set,∅, and then I can select either {a},{b}, or {c} for the next element and depending on what element I select I have three different elements to select from.

This is the beginning of my list:
∅, {a},{b},{c},{a,b},{a,c},{b,c},{a,b,c}

∅, {a},{b},{c},{b,c},{a,b},{a,c},{a,b,c}

∅, {a},{b},{c},{a,c },{b,c},{a,b},{a,b,c}

∅, {a},{b},{a,b},{c},{a,c},{b,c},{a,b,c}

∅, {a},{b},{a,b},{c},{b,c},{a,c},{a,b,c}

∅, {a},{c},{a,c},{b},{a,b},{b,c},{a,b,c}

∅, {a},{c},{a,c},{b},{b,c},{a,b},{a,b,c}

This will go on and on….

Is there a formula to find the number of linear extensions?
Is it something like this… 
(1 choose 1)(3 choose 1) (3 choose 1)(2 choose 1)(3 choose 1)(2 choose 1) (1 choose 1)(1 choose 1)

Comment: How do you define a linear extension?

Comment: @Ju'x: It is a linear order $\preceq$ such that $A\subseteq B\implies A\preceq B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider choosing subsets in order after the empty set. Note that you must choose two singeletons first, for which there are $6$ ordered choices. Then you either choose the next singleton (one choice), or you choose the 2-subset with the first two singletons in it (one choice). In the first case, you can order the 2-subsets afterward in any way you want (6 choices), and in the second case then the remaining singleton must come next and then the remaining two 2-subsets can come in any order ($2$ choices). So you get $6(6 + 2) = 48$ as the answer.